# SQL Query time spent between certain value

Tags: sql-server, date, common-table-expression

I have a database for all temperatures the last 10 years.
Now I want to find all periods where the temperature was above ex. 15 degree.

```
Simplified example:
...
2015-05-10  12 
2015-05-11  15 |
2015-05-12  16 |
2015-05-13  17 |
2015-05-14  16 |
2015-05-15  15 |
2015-05-16  12
2015-05-17  11
2015-05-18  15 |
2015-05-19  12
2015-05-20  18 |
...
```

Så now I want get all time periods like this:

```
Min         Max
2015-05-11  2015-05-15
2015-05-18  2015-05-18
2015-05-20  2015-05-20
```

Any suggestion of how this query will look like ?

Comment: looks like a variant of the gaps and islands problem. you want to find islands of rows that have a value above 15 and treat the other rows like gaps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CTE

```
CREATE TABLE #Date (DateT datetime, Value int )

INSERT INTO #Date 
VALUES ('2015-05-10',12), 
       ('2015-05-11',15), 
       ('2015-05-12',16), 
       ('2015-05-13',17), 
       ('2015-05-14',16), 
       ('2015-05-15',15), 
       ('2015-05-16',12), 
       ('2015-05-17',11), 
       ('2015-05-18',15), 
       ('2015-05-19',12), 
       ('2015-05-20',18)



WITH t AS (
          SELECT  DateT d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateT) i
          FROM #Date
          WHERE Value >= 15
          GROUP BY DateT
        )


SELECT MIN(d) as DataStart,MAX(d) as DataFinal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day,i,d)) as RN
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,i,d)
```

RN column is optional you could use

```
 SELECT MIN(d) as DataStart,MAX(d) as DataFinal 
 FROM t
 GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,i,d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a gaps and islands algorithm. It looks kind of bulky but it runs fast and scales great. It is also modular if you want to add a gap-allowed parameter and you can rewrite it to partition by some other columns and it still performs nicely.

Inspired by Peter Larssons post here: http://www.sqltopia.com/?page_id=83

```
WITH [theSource](Col1,Col2)
AS
(
SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM (VALUES 
('2015-05-10',12),
('2015-05-11',15),
('2015-05-12',16),
('2015-05-13',17),
('2015-05-14',16),
('2015-05-15',15),
('2015-05-16',12),
('2015-05-17',11),
('2015-05-18',15),
('2015-05-19',12),
('2015-05-20',18)
) as x(Col1,Col2)
)
,filteredSource([Value])
AS
(
SELECT Col1 as [Value]
FROM theSource WHERE Col2 >= 15
)
,cteSource(RangeStart, RangeEnd)
AS (
    SELECT  RangeStart,
        CASE WHEN [RangeStart] = [RangeEnd] THEN [RangeEnd] ELSE LEAD([RangeEnd]) OVER (ORDER BY Value) END AS [RangeEnd]
        FROM    (
            SELECT  [Value],
                CASE
                    WHEN DATEADD(DAY,1,LAG([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Value])) >= [Value] THEN NULL
                    ELSE [Value]
                END AS RangeStart,
                CASE
                    WHEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,LEAD([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Value])) <= [Value] THEN NULL
                    ELSE [Value]
                                END AS RangeEnd
                        FROM    filteredSource
                ) AS d
    WHERE   RangeStart IS NOT NULL
        OR RangeEnd IS NOT NULL
)


SELECT  RangeStart AS [Min],
    RangeEnd AS [Max]
FROM    cteSource
WHERE   RangeStart IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: What if you have a gap in days? Say if you are missing data for some days during 10 years